# Posting to a specific facebook user's timeline from ios xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-feed

I'm trying to figure out how to post from xcode to a specific user's timeline. I found a lot of posts but they seemed to be for older versions of the facebook sdk.

I'm looking here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4

And the only option I'm seeing is to use url redirection.

I'm looking here for options here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

But I'm not seeing any way to specify it to post to a different user's timeline.

So is the url redirection the only way to do it? What I want to do is press a button on my ios app, and then have it post to a facebook wall. If I use url redirection, it will open up a browser... do the posting and then redirect somewhere... where I assume I will have javascript code to close the browser.

Are there any other options? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only post to the timeline of the logged in user. Posting to the timeline of one or more friends of the user is not supported.